# How would you write $\sinh(4θ)$ in terms of $\cosh(4θ)$ and $\sinh(4θ)$, all in relation to the function $e^{4θ}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, hyperbolic-functions

I know the hyperbolic identites but I cant seem to find a way to do it involving $\cosh(4θ)$ and $\sinh(4θ)$.

Comment: $\sinh(4\theta)$ is already expressed in terms of $\cosh(4\theta)$ and $\sinh(4\theta)$, quite obviously... did you mean in terms of $\cosh\theta$ and $\sinh\theta$? You can express it in terms of $e^{4\theta}$ just using the definition of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$...

Comment: well its asking for it in terms of cosh(4θ) and sinh(4θ)

Comment: That doesn't make sense. $\sinh(4\theta)$ is already in terms of $\sinh(4\theta)$, it is itself!

Comment: does it make any difference if you look at different ways e^θ(4) can be computed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean writing $\cosh(4\theta)$ and $\sinh(4\theta)$ in terms of $e^{4\theta}$ in which case, 
$$\cosh(4\theta)=\frac{e^{4\theta}+e^{-4\theta}}{2}$$ 
$$\sinh(4\theta)=\frac{e^{4\theta}-e^{-4\theta}}{2}$$ 
Using the above, you get : $$\cosh^2 (4\theta)-\sinh^2 (4\theta)=1$$